# Does the following generalization of the Ashkin-Teller model make sense

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, lattice-model

Ashkin-Teller (AT) model has interesting properties. I learned this from some threads here on PhysSE, particularly the [recent one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/784255/178206). In short, the AT model can be described as two layers of Ising spins. Inside the layers, the spins interact by the usual two-spin interaction, the interaction between the layers is four-spin. There is an obvious generalization of such a model to the case with many layers. For example, in the case of one-dimensional layers, the energy of the original AT model has the form
$$
E_o = -\sum_{i}\left(J_1(\sigma_{i,1}\sigma_{i+1,1} + \sigma_{i,2}\sigma_{i+1,2}) + J_2\ \sigma_{i,1}\sigma_{i+1,1}\sigma_{i,2}\sigma_{i+1,2}\right)
$$
and for the generalized model it will be
$$
E_g = -\sum_{i,j}\left(J_1\ \sigma_{i,j}\sigma_{i+1,j} + J_2\ \sigma_{i,j}\sigma_{i+1,j}\sigma_{i,j+1}\sigma_{i+1,j+1}\right).
$$
In this example, the original model is one-dimensional, although consisting of two layers, and the generalized model is two-dimensional with an extremely anisotropic interaction. My question is: are models with such anisotropy studied in statistical physics? Are such models of any interest?

Comment: Such generalizations have been proposed; see for instance [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.24.6508). Even more general versions have been proposed (for instance, in Section 5 of [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02732435)). I don't know whether a detailed analysis of such generalizations has been done, which is why I refrain from giving a proper answer...

Comment: @YvanVelenik I was hoping you might know something about this topic. Thank you very much.