# Coupling two Ising chains via an energy-energy interaction

Tags: conformal-field-theory, phase-transition, ising-model, phase-diagram, spin-chains

Consider the transverse-field Ising model on a chain with periodic boundary conditions:

$$ H = -\sum_{i=1}^{L} \sigma_{i}^z \sigma_{i+1}^z + h \sigma_{i}^x$$

There's a phase transition at $h=1$, which is consistent with Kramers-Wannier duality. This phase transition is in the 2d classical Ising universality class described by a conformal field theory with central charge $c=\frac{1}{2}$.

---

I want to understand what happens when I have two Ising chains that I couple with similar terms. In particular, I have two chains $a$ and $b$ that I couple with energy-energy interactions:

$$\begin{split} H =& -\sum_{i=1}^{L} \left( \sigma_{(a),i}^z \sigma_{(a),i+1}^z + h \sigma_{(a),i}^x \right)
\\ & -\sum_{i=1}^{L}\left(  \sigma_{(b),i}^z \sigma_{(b),i+1}^z + h \sigma_{(b),i}^x \right)
\\& -\lambda \sum_{i=1}^{L} \left( \sigma_{(a),i}^z \sigma_{(a),i+1}^z + h \sigma_{(a),i}^x \right)  \left( \sigma_{(b),i}^z \sigma_{(b),i+1}^z + h \sigma_{(b),i}^x \right) \end{split}$$

I am interested in the case of $\lambda$ small and positive, like $\lambda=.1$.
In particular, I expect that at $h=1$ there will be a phase transition that will not be described by two decoupled Ising transitions but rather by a $c=1$ model with continuously varying exponents as a function of the small positive $\lambda$.

My reasoning for the above is because the above quantum model reminds me of the Ashkin-Teller model with two coupled classical Ising planes, and the phase diagram was discussed in the question and answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/784255/phase-diagram-of-the-ashkin-teller-model-for-unequal-intraplane-couplings) and in one of the [papers](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00220-003-1008-0) mentioned there, where small interplane coupling gave rise to a single phase transition.

To make explicit my question: Does the above coupled Ising model for small positive lambda ($\lambda=.1$, say) have a phase transition at $h=1$, and if so, what is its universality? Can I interpret it as a $c=1$ model with continuously critical exponents varying as a function of the small positive $\lambda$?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my mind about the phase transition. I believe that the added term, rewritten appropriately to absorb certain marginal factors, is actually irrelevant. I would appreciate answers with other perspectives, however.

First, consider rewriting $\sigma_{i}^z \sigma_{i+1}^z + h \sigma_{i}^x = (\sigma_{i}^z \sigma_{i+1}^z + h \sigma_{i}^x - e_0(h))+e_0(h)$, where $e_0$ is the expectation value of $\sigma_{i}^z \sigma_{i+1}^z + h \sigma_{i}^x$ in the ground state of $-\sum_{i=1}^{L} \left( \sigma_{i}^z \sigma_{i+1}^z + h \sigma_{i}^x \right)$.

Then we have

$$\begin{split} H =& -(1+\lambda e_0(h))\sum_{i=1}^{L} \left( \sigma_{(a),i}^z \sigma_{(a),i+1}^z + h \sigma_{(a),i}^x \right)
\\ & -(1+\lambda e_0(h))\sum_{i=1}^{L}\left(  \sigma_{(b),i}^z \sigma_{(b),i+1}^z + h \sigma_{(b),i}^x \right)
\\& -\lambda \sum_{i=1}^{L} \left( \sigma_{(a),i}^z \sigma_{(a),i+1}^z + h \sigma_{(a),i}^x - e_0(h)\right )  \left( \sigma_{(b),i}^z \sigma_{(b),i+1}^z + h \sigma_{(b),i}^x - e_0(h)\right) \end{split}$$

At the critical point of $h=1$, $\left( \sigma_{(a),i}^z \sigma_{(a),i+1}^z + h \sigma_{(a),i}^x - e_0(h)\right )$ is an operator with vanishing expectation value in the decoupled limit that can be interpreted in terms of the stress-energy tensor of the Ising CFT; that is, I expect this term to be marginal at the transition with scaling dimension $\Delta=2$.

However, I expect the product $\left( \sigma_{(a),i}^z \sigma_{(a),i+1}^z + h \sigma_{(a),i}^x - e_0(h)\right )  \left( \sigma_{(b),i}^z \sigma_{(b),i+1}^z + h \sigma_{(b),i}^x - e_0(h)\right)$ to have a scaling dimension $2+2=4$, so I expect this term to be irrelevant at the Ising fixed point.

---

While I don't mind the factors of $\lambda e_0(h)$ in the prefactors of the within-chain couplings, I feel a little bit uncertain about the $h$-dependence of the between-chain couplings. I feel that since at $h=1$ my perturbation is irrelevant, then the critical exponents controlled by the $h=1$ point should remain the same. The reason I'm a little uncomfortable is because I think a subset of critical behavior is described by the $h\to1$ limit and not just the properties of the $h=1$ point, and I'm less comfortable about the former.

To be more specific, I think I would be more comfortable if my Hamiltonian were
$$\begin{split} H' =& -\sum_{i=1}^{L} \left( \sigma_{(a),i}^z \sigma_{(a),i+1}^z + h \sigma_{(a),i}^x \right)
\\ & -\sum_{i=1}^{L}\left(  \sigma_{(b),i}^z \sigma_{(b),i+1}^z + h \sigma_{(b),i}^x \right)
\\& -\lambda \sum_{i=1}^{L} \left( \sigma_{(a),i}^z \sigma_{(a),i+1}^z +  \sigma_{(a),i}^x - e_0(1)\right )  \left( \sigma_{(b),i}^z \sigma_{(b),i+1}^z +  \sigma_{(b),i}^x - e_0(1)\right) \end{split}$$
Note that at $h=1$ this matches my original Hamiltonian (up to a minor rescaling of $\lambda$), but the added perturbation is $h$-independent.

However, I suspect and hope that the critical behavior given by $H$ and $H'$ will be identical, not just at $h=1$ but also in the approach to $h=1$.